# Why don't I have a "Make Google Chrome the default browser" button in my Chrome settings?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, default-settings

My Chrome settings says "Google Chrome is not currently your default browser." But there's no button that allows me to set Chrome as the default browser:

[image]

Running Windows 7 x64. Absolutely baffled. Can't seem to find anything on Google. "Run as Administrator" doesn't change anything. IE and Firefox both have their "Make default" buttons present, so I don't think it's a network policy thing? Tried setting FireFox as the default then coming back to Chrome; still nothing.

Comment: How did you install chrome? I know that when you are using a portable version of chrome you cannot set it as default.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try the following.

1. Press [image] key to get search box. Type `default` and you’ll get `Default Programs` as a result.
2. Select `Google Chrome` and click **Set this program as default**. Click **OK**.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, if I click a link in an email or something, it'll open in Chrome but if I look at my registry `HTTP\\shell\\open\\command` is still set to FireFox... Would it be a bad to delete that and put in the path to Chrome? We've got an application at work that uses this key and I don't want it to keep opening FireFox, but at the same time I don't want to *remove* FF from my system all together.

Comment: **This is not answering the question.** Sure, you can do it the *Windows way*, but why is the option not available in Chrome Settings?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I installed chrome again (without removing the first installation), this time by the offline standalone setup, for all users. I now have two chrome installations. I deleted the old one, which didn't delete my history/passwords/bookmarks. But I now have chrome as default browser, and it also showed up in default programs window, which it wasn't before.

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, click on "System Preferences -> General -> Default web browser" to pick the browser. I'm on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. OP is using Windows not Mac.

Comment: I know the question was for Windows, but I had the same problem on my Mac, so I put the answer here to help other Mac users.